# Greater than, Less than string Lua (Lapis)

Tags: nginx, lua

I'm trying to return string `"<a>"` , but I received empty string.
That is,

```
"<a>" => (nothing but not nil)
"PP<a>" => PP
"R".."<a>" => R
"R:" .. (string.format("<%s>", "a")) => R
```

I haven't found in documentation this feature.

Can you help my understand why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you're viewing it in an application where the HTML tags are parsed. You'd need to escape the `<` and `>` characters:

```
"&lt;a&gt;"
```

Comment: You are genious:) You really helped. Thanks) That's was so obvious:)